# Android Wear says it needs to update Google Play Services but nothing happens

Tags: android-wear

I've installed Android Wear on my Lollipop device and when it launches it says it needs a new version of Google Play Services. But when I click on the Update Google Play Services button nothing happens.
I tried searching for Google Play Services on the play store but it doesn't appear in the search results (but it does appear in the results if I search on a laptop browser, but it doesn't if searching directly on the phone).
How can I update the damn thing to get Android Wear to work??

Comment: It should just do it behind the scenes.  Is it repeatedly prompting you?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue recently when using transit app. This is how i updated Google Play Service. On your Android Wear go to settings -> About -> Versions -> Google Play services. When you press on Google Play service it will check for update and install it.

Comment: Procedure is correct but when it deems to work and not work seems spotty at best.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) entry for Google Play Services in case you're looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Play Store > Settings on your lollipop device.
Click Build Version.
Do you see a dialog telling you if Play Store is up to date?
Does it now update itself if necessary?